# How to make container avoid float like its inner text

Tags: css

I feel like there should be an easy answer to this.  I have a sidebar floated to the right, when I noticed there were some issues on the hover.  Turns out my

```
<p>
```

tags on the left were crossing over into the float, even though the text inside them properly avoided the float.  I made a simple jsfiddle example to show what I mean, and turned their backgrounds on so you can see them overlapping.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahvs3nr3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this CSS fixes the problem:

```
p {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ft2h7k6/)**

In your code, the *container* (`p`) overflowed the sidebar, even though its *content* was constrained to not overflow.

From the [**W3 spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html):

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers 
>   ... that are not block
>   boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' ... establish new
>   block formatting contexts for their contents.

This is what led me to try `overflow: auto`.

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
>   box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box
>   establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box
>   itself may become narrower due to the floats).

This explains why the container overflows the sidebar, but its "line box" (which contains its text) does not.

So what exactly is a "line box"?

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one
>   after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block.
>   Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these
>   boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their
>   bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them
>   may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form
>   a line is called a line box.  The width of a line box is determined by a
>   containing block and the presence of floats.

There are no explicit inline elements, so what causes this "inline formatting context"?

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
>   (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline
>   element.

And there you have it.  The text *within* each paragraph is an "anonymous inline element," which creates a "line box," which is influenced by floats.

Comment: Nice... I like this one even better.  It's like the same solution as clearing floats.  Having trouble with floats?  overflow: auto!!!

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Use `overflow` to create a BFC to figure out float problems is simple and nice, but it also create some problems. Use auto will display scroll bar (http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/qa354se3/). If you want to figure out float problems, I support use .clearfix see http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/

Comment: @sdcr, very interesting!  My overflow solution creates a scrollbar, because the image doesn't fit within the boundaries.  Your table solution causes the content to move below the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the `<p>` tag is a block element. Will this work in your case?

```
p {
    display: table;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahvs3nr3/3/

Comment: Wow, it feels like a hack, but it does do exactly what I need it to.  I did try other display values before with no luck, but I didn't try table.  You think that's the only way to get it to work?

Comment: I'm quite surprised I have never encountered that before, I guess I normally use it on `<span>` tags. This is the easiest way that I know atm. Also tested padding and margin all work fine with display: table. What else do we need.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some margin right of the p tags.

```
.sidebar {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    float:right;
    width:25%;
    height:30em;
}

p { background:red; padding:1em; margin-right: 25%; }
```

I also added a jsfiddle for reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/ahvs3nr3/2/

I use % margins here because they will adapt to any width browser however if you want to use a 5em sidebar just make sure the p tags have the same amount of margin right.

Comment: The sidebar width is not constant and cannot be represented by a percentage.  I guess I could make a few media queries for each break point, but it just feels like if the text can avoid the float, there should be a rule that would allow the container to do the same.

Comment: I use grid layouts myself for dealing with this issue. It relies on percentages and is quite responsive. I do have to use media queries but that is to be expected to transition a page layout from regular width to phone width.